# Chicago biblatex, @legislation, get rid of post key "at"

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

I'm using `biblatex-chicago`, and have a few references of the `@legislation` type. If I use `\autocite[p.~12]{Test2020}`, I get "...(Test 2020, at p. 12)". If it's just `@journal`, I do not get an "at". How can I change this? I suppose I have to renew a command, but I am not sure which one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`biblatex-chicago` implements the style(s) described in the Chicago Manual of Style as closely as possible. As far as I understand Chicago Style follows Bluebook recommendations when it comes to legal citations. Apparently one of those recommendations is the inclusion of 'at' for pinpoint references.

If you need to cite legal references, I strongly suggest you double check whether or not the 'at' should be included in the citation and whether `@legislation` is the correct entry type. (`biblatex-chicago` also offers the type `@jurisdiction` for legal cases and court decisions as well as `@legal` as a fallback in case neither `@jurisdiction` nor `@legislation` work particularly well.)

The following modification will remove 'at's from postnotes in `biblatex-chicago`. It is not clear whether that is the best solution in your case, but without more details to go by, it is all I can offer at the moment.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[authordate, 
backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\renewrobustcmd*{\mkjuridprefix}[1]{\addcomma\space#1}%

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@legislation{lorem,
  title     = {Lex Lorem},
  year      = {1972},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[12]{lorem}
ipsum \autocite[379]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Lex Lorem 1972, 12) ipsum (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, 379)]

Not that it would be relevant, but neither `biblatex-chicago` nor standard `biblatex` recognise a type `@journal`. There is `@article` for an article in a journal or `@periodical` for an entire volume/number of a journal (`@periodical` isn't used very often).

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm! Re: @journal, that was a typo, re: publication type, I only use hearings which is an entrysubtype for legislation. I have no specific guidelines how to cite hearings, so I just follow chicago, yet, the "at" bothered me since I often add emphasis to certain statements.